# Sending a cURL POST request as a link

Tags: python, django, curl, post, lamp

I have a LAMP Django API that sends out a text message to my customer which says Click [This Link] to do A and [Another Link] to do B.

I've been using POST requests to take in data to my API but that's been me polling directly from cURL in cmd. I want to create the request, then be able to send it out as a link to my client, then they click it and the post request is sent to my API.

Is this possible?

UPDATE: I have an ID number attached to each user. So this ID needs to persist from the API to the text and back to the API somehow.

Comment: Probably no. The link will open in a mobile browser, which will make a GET request. Instead, you can redirect the GET request to the POST request from your server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use something like the [requests](https://3.python-requests.org/) library. The only thing you need to do then is create a GET View, link your CLICK HERE so it resolves to that view, and then simply send the POST request from said View.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views import View
import requests

class MyView(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        requests.post(your_url_here, data=your_body, headers=your_headers)
        return HttpResponse('POST request sent!')
```

Comment: I like this idea. Although I forgot to mention something important. I'll edit my post. I have an ID # that is attached to the user I send a text to. If I send a GET to the user then I lose that ID and then don't know what data to attach to the POST.

Comment: You can pass query params as input to the API.

Comment: You can always make your GET View use a parameter, such as /send-post-request/<id>, so then you know what data to attach.

So the click here would redirect you to something like:

`/send-post-request/23232`, and then in your view you can access 23232

Comment: Ah perfect! Thanks!